# Source in the Gemara for having homosexual relations with yourself

Tags: talmud-gemara, homosexuality

Is there a Halachic question that is brought down somewhere in Shas regarding the question of whether it is forbidden for a Jew to have homosexual relations with himself? I imagine that, if possible, it would involve someone who is somewhat double-jointed. But I don't care if it's possible. I'm just look for a source in Shas that discusses it.

Comment: similar regarding heterosexual relations with yourself http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35437/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sanhedrin 55a

> בעא מיניה רב אחדבוי בר אמי מרב ששת המערה בעצמו מהו אמר ליה קבסתן אמר רב אשי מאי תיבעי לך בקושי לא משכחת לה כי משכחת לה במשמש מת למאן דאמר משמש מת בעריות פטור הכא פטור ולמאן דאמר חייב הכא מיחייב תרתי מיחייב אשוכב ומיחייב אנשכב